# How do I get reflective surface in Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Which shader is to be used for an object when the object has reflective surface of the real world. It is for an AR application, similar to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4Mo1NjXYu4. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't .. Vuforia uses visual tracking ... if your surface is reflecting then you can't "see" it good enough

Comment: @derHugo but the user in the video is using Vuforia itself.

Comment: yes ... but he is tracking a normal image target and spawns a virtual object onto it ... the reflective surface is here only the material of the 3D model ...

Comment: @derHugo yes even the wall is being reflected on it. How to do this? Is there a particular shader to use?

Comment: ahh my bad now I got what you want .. this is everything but trivial actually since it requires you to access the image of the camera and calculate it into a reflection map/texture or something .. unfortunately far to broad for this community.

Comment: @derHugo True, we can render continuously from the camera's view and add it to a render texture, the render texture can then be used on an object's material. I think this should work.